# Conteo y suma condicional para dos columnas - Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Tengo una tabla exportada con esta estructura:

| Dia | Dia_factura | Valor | Estado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 12500 |  |
| 0 |  | 3300 |  |
| 6 |  | 2750 |  |
| 6 | 13 | 1000 | Activo |
| 6 | 0 | 670 | Activo |
| 7 | 13 | 490 | Activo |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | Activo |
| 9 | 13 | 0 | Activo |
| 13 |  | 0 |  |
| 13 | 13 | 0 | Activo |
| 13 |  | 330 | Activo |
| 13 | 13 | 9750 | Activo |
| 13 | 0 | 100 |  |

Y tengo una visdualizacion de una tabla, la cual tiene la columna dia con dos medidas, el conteo de registros para un estado "Activo" y la suma del valor segun el estado (ambos generados por una medida), quedando visualmente asi:

| Dia | Conteo | Suma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | 4420 |
| 7 | 1 | 490 |
| 9 | 2 | 0 |
| 13 | 3 | 10080 |

El asunto es que necesito crear una medida, la cual haga el mismo conteo y suma pero para los dias facturados (Agruparse por el dia facturado, por decirlo en vez del dia)... Debiese quedar asi:

| Dia | Conteo | Suma | Conteo Facturados | Suma Facturados |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | 4420 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 490 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 3 | 10080 | 5 | 11240 |

Si se fijan, de la tabla principal debe realizar el conteo y la suma respectiva y que se muestre en el dia indicado (no se si se entienda)

Las medidas que tengo de conteo y suma para la columna "dia" funcionan bien:

Conteo y suma:

```
CALCULATE( COUNT(Tabla[Dia]), Tabla[Estado] = "Activo")
CALCULATE( SUM(Tabla[Valor]), Tabla[Estado] = "Activo")
```

El drama viene cuando quiero utilizar calculate, pero usando estas condicionales, ya que no me calcula como indico mas arriba:

```
CALCULATE( COUNT(Tabla[Dia_factura]), Tabla[Estado] = "Activo", Tabla[Dia_factura] > 0, NOT(ISBLANK(Tabla[Dia_factura]) ))
```

Esta medida me termina generando esto, donde los valores se duplican, y en este caso, en el dia 13 no muestra nada:

| Dia | Conteo | Suma | Conteo Facturados | Suma Facturados |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | 4420 | 3 | 11000 |
| 7 | 1 | 490 | 3 | 11000 |
| 9 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 240 |
| 13 | 3 | 10080 |  |  |

Espero se entienda y me puedan ayudar